# JAXB marshall without parent element

Tags: jaxb, xmladapter

There are two JavaBean A and B. and 2 String C and D.
There structure is

```
A
--B
----C
----D
```

I can marshall Object A to Xml

```
<A>
  <B>
   <C>ccc</C>
   <D>ddd</D>
  </B>
</A>
```

And In some cases, I'd like to marshall A to XML like this

```
<A>
   <C>ccc</C>
   <D>ddd</D>
</A>
```

Without B tag.
can it be done by XMLAdapter, or other ways.
it' the best if it has some dynamic ways.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could leverage MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension for this use case:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    @XmlPath(".")
    private B b;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Thanks, is the any ways that JAXB (JSR-222) supports?

Comment: I tried this approach and the example from your blog but still the `JAXB Marshalling` does not work as expected with `@XmlPath`. Seems like the XML produced with and without `@XmlPath` are same. Can you please once look into this example and provide your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500565/xmlpath-has-no-impact-during-the-jaxb-marshalling