# @XmlPath has no impact during the JAXB Marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am trying to create XML using the `JaxB Marshalling` approach. I want to skip the parent tag for certain children or may add a new `XML` parent tag for a certain element. Hence I am trying to use the `@XmlPath` from `import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;`.

I am following the blog from the founder ([Blog on @XmlPath](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html)) to make it work but for some reason, the `@XmlPath` has no impact and the output XML does not match as shown in the blog. I followed all the process mentioned within the blog and also mentioned on various answers here.

All my classes are within the `model.jaxb` package. Also, I have created a `jaxb.properties` file within that package.

Following is my `Customer` class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

  @XmlPath("contact-info/billing-address")
  private Address billingAddress;

  @XmlPath("contact-info/shipping-address")
  private Address shippingAddress;

}
```

Following is my `Address` class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Address {

  private String street;

}
```

Following is `Demo` class:

```
public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

    Customer customer = new Customer();

    Address billingAddress = new Address();
    billingAddress.setStreet("1 Billing Street");
    customer.setBillingAddress(billingAddress);

    Address shippingAddress = new Address();
    shippingAddress.setStreet("2 Shipping Road");
    customer.setShippingAddress(shippingAddress);

    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    m.marshal(customer, System.out);
  }

}
```

The XML I getting with and without `@XmlPath` are the same actually. So seems like the `@XmlPath` has no impact during the marshalling.

```
<customer>
    <billingAddress>
        <street>1 Billing Street</street>
    </billingAddress>
    <shippingAddress>
        <street>2 Shipping Road</street>
    </shippingAddress>
</customer>
```

I have created `jaxb.properties` file within my `package model.jaxb` with the content:

`javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`

As per the blog the output XML should be something like this:

```
<customer>
   <contact-info>
      <billing-address>
         <street>1 Billing Street</street>
      </billing-address>
      <shipping-address>
         <street>2 Shipping Road</street>
      </shipping-address>
   </contact-info>
<customer>
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong due to which I am unable to get the XML as I expect. I tried a lot of things but none worked so posting the same here.

Can someone please help me with how can I make the `@XmlPath` kicking during the marshalling so that I can get the expected tag during the marshalling?

**** EDITED *****

I am using Java version 15.0.01 as per the `Intellij IDE File -> Project Structure`. I saw one answer where it mentioned `Moxy` does not work directly above `Java 11` [Answer Java 11.0 above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60285555/7584240).

So I did following things:

1. I added the dependency and `build` as mentioned in the above answer so my `pom.xml` looks something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
          <groupId>model.jaxb</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
      <artifactId>model-jaxb</artifactId>
    
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <source>8</source>
              <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    
      <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.16</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
        
      </dependencies>
    
    </project>
```

When I run the program then I get the error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException`

I tried a lot of things mentioned on `StackOverflow for this error and most of the answers mentioned adding the` dependency` I have added all the dependency mentioned in the answer. I am not sure what's going wrong.

Can someone please assist me with how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does your `pom.xml` file have a build step which ensures the `jaxb.properties` file is bundled into the JAR (or WAR) built by Maven?

Comment: I added a note about the required Maven build step to my answer in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60285555/12567365), in case that helps. Apart from that, I am not able to recreate your problem. Your code generates the expected XML when I use it with this extra build step (but not without!).

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking out and providing the answer. I was somewhat able to figure out the issue. I added my `jaxb.properties` file within the folder `resources->model->jaxb` same structure as my `domain classes which will be used by jaxb` after that I added the dependecy mentioned in your answer and two more dependencies such as `org.glassfish.jaxb` and `jakarta.xml.bind`. Now its throwing me the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext`

Comment: OK - but if you revert to the dependencies in my other answer, and if you add the **step regarding the Maven build,** then does it work for you (because your code works for me). Then you can start adjusting dependencies if you need to - but you will be doing that from a config which works.

Comment: Thanks for your response and taking time. I actually followed the steps mentioned in your answer and lots of other resources and made the modification accordingly but still I am seeing that `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFo undError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext` issue. I have modified the question based on this issue. Can you please have look at the `edited` section in this question and provide your guidence?

Comment: Regarding your notes _"I added the jaxb.properties file within my resource folder"_: Your properties file should not be placed in a `resources` folder. It needs to be in the same location as your Java source files - namely the `model.jaxb` package. Creating a copy of that directory structure in `resources` is a different thing entirely. Your Maven `build` command will ensure that the properties file is copied to the same target location as your compiled `class` files.  You can open the JAR file to check it ends up in the right place.

Comment: @andrewjames Actually I placed both places in the `Java Classes` folder and in the `resources` folder just to see if that would make any difference. Now after your comment I removed the file from the `Resources` folder. So now it's just present within the same package as my `java classes`. This is providing me the XML but the XML does not take the `@XmlPath` elements into account. With or without the `@XmlPath` it's producing the same XML so I am not sure what's going wrong here. Because you used the same code and it's working for you but for some reason its not working for me. What can I try?

Comment: The only thing I can see that is different between your code and mine is the use of Lombok (I am not using it). That should not make any difference...

Comment: Actually, the error still exists after removing the `jaxb.properties` file from the `resources` folder. Most of the answer mention that the error is due to the missing `dependency` I have added all the required dependencies but still get the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException`

Comment: Why do you have `jakarta.xml.bind` in your dependencies?

Comment: That's what most of the answers mentioned for the issue so I was trying that as well: `jakarta.xml.bind` and `org.glassfish.jaxb`. For Java 11 and above they are saying we need to use this dependency. If I remove that then also I am getting errors. If I add then also I am getting errors. I am very much confused about what needs to be done. Should I remove both or just the one `jakarta.xml.bind`? Here is a link to what I was referring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/7584240

Comment: Remove all your dependencies. Then add back just these two: `<dependency><groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId><artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId><version>2.3.1</version></dependency>` and  `<dependency><groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId><artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId><version>2.7.6</version></dependency>`. Tell me what happens.

Comment: Sure, so I removed all of my dependencies and added just the 3 dependencies which you provided (and Lombok) and ran the `Demo.class` which has the `JaxBContent`. I am getting the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException` after few lines of error I have this line as well `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException`

Comment: This should work for an **older** version of MOXy (v2.7). Then to upgrade to the **latest & greatest** version of MOXy, see my latest updates to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388961/not-able-to-configure-moxy-using-jaxb/60285555#60285555). See the new section "UPDATES for MOXy version 3".

Comment: I only provided 2 dependencies not 3, in my comment. Sorry - but I don't know what changes you are making - they do not match my comments. Anyway, see my notes about "latest and greatest".

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry I added just those 2 dependencies including Lombok 3 I meant I am really sorry for the mistake. Actually, I am not making any changes apart from what you have asked me to do. Now I am trying to implement based on your updated answer from your post.

Comment: OK - good luck!

Comment: I tried the updated code from your post. 1. I updated the `jaxb.properties` file content to `jakarta` (replaced old line with a new one). 2. Added the new dependencies to `pom.xml` with versions 3.0.0 (removed old and just kept new dependencies). 3. Changed the imports in `Demo.class` to `jakarta` from `jaxb`. when I run I am getting following error: `Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: jaxb.properties in package (link to package) does not contain the javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory property.`

Comment: I recommend starting again from scratch with a completely new Java project. I think there have been so many changes you have tried, that something is seriously out-of-step now in your code/config. These errors are basically "impossible" given the dependencies you should be using. (Also, do make sure you are performing a complete clean & build after every change you make.) And try without Lombok, to start with. Add it back in once you have something that actually works.

Comment: Sure, I will follow your instructions and create from scratch. Post my observations here after trying. Thanks a lot again for being so patient and guiding.

Comment: Hi, Yes finally it worked. I was missing one small thing my `Customer.class` was still using the `imports` from `jaxb` instead of `Jakarta`. I was again analysing the whole thing found that. I changed all the imports to `Jakarta` and boom it worked and able to get the `XML` as I expected. Also, the `@XmlPath` is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and for guiding me through this error. It took my whole day to understand and fix. Finally, at the end of the day, I was able to get it. Thanks to you :) If possible please provide the answer from your post here and maybe some more points so that people can find answers quickly and they do not end up spending so much time. I will accept the answer so you get some reward for your efforts.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Nice! You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here to described how you fixed your problem - your own perspective will be helpful. If you want to (and doing this is of course 100% optional), you can vote for the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60285555/12567365) as well.

Comment: @andrewjames I have one small doubt. Now everything is working fine and able to get my address like this in XML: `      <billing-address>
         <street>1 Billing Street</street>
      </billing-address>`. Now what if I want to skip the `<street>` tag using the `@XmlPath`? I tried to add the following `@XmlPath(".")` and `@XmlPath("./text()")` but both throw the error. I want to add the `street` value directly to the `<billing-address>` so that I can skip the `<street>` tag. I was planning to use the `@XmlPath` for this main reason actually. Is it possible to do using the `@XmlPath`?Thanks

Comment: @andrewjames Never mind. I got it. I just added the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to my `Address.class` and that worked so now the `street` tag is directly mapped to `customer` tag and `billing-address` has been skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally was able to find the solution with a lot of assist from @andrewjames. Posting the solution for the same so somebody can find the solution quickly and do not end up spending whole day like me :)

You can also follow the steps mentioned by @andrewjames [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388961/not-able-to-configure-moxy-using-jaxb/60285555#60285555).

1. Make sure you have only ONE copy of `jaxb.properties` file within the same package as of the domain class (the one which will be used during the marshalling in this case the `Customer.class`). The content of the file should be:

   jakarta.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory

2.Remove all the dependency from your `pom.xml` file and just add the following 2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3. Make sure all your classes (in this case `Customer.class` and `Demo.ckass`) are using the imports from `import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;`.

Previously it was taking from `import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;` should be replaced from `import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;`.

I was making changes to `Demo.class` and forgot to change in `Customer.class` so was seeing some `defclass` issue. So make sure all your class uses the imports from `Jakarta` and not from `Javax`.

4. Add the following `<build>` to your `pom.xml`:

```
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
```

5. After making these changes run the `Demo.class` this should give you the expected XML. Also `@XmlPath` should work as expected.

Following are some of the mistakes I was making. You can check if you are not making them:

1. I was having too many dependencies and some were duplicated also. Such as dependencies from `com.sun.activation`, `javax.activation`, `javax.validation`, `org.glassfish.jaxb`, etc. These were mentioned in other answers so I was trying everything. Better remove all and make a fresh start and add only the once needed. For this case, only 2 mentioned in `step-2` would be sufficient.
2. The answers mentioned in most of the post on `Stackoverflow` is for the old version. Including the articles and blogs on various website. As there has been some changes after `Java 11` better use the latest version and the steps mentioned in this answer or the other answer provided with the link above.
3. Make sure you clean and rebuild the maven project because sometimes the `dependencies` are not directly added when you save the `pom.xml` file. At least in my case when I was using the `Intellij IDE`. I was doing clean and build every time I added the dependency so that I am making sure everything is fine from `Maven` side.

That's all the points I feel sufficient for making this work. If you are still facing some issue then leave a comment on the other post or here. I will try to answer if I can. Have a nice day.